# programname.exe has Stopped Working dialog in windows 10

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, gcc, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 , TDM-GCC with Eclipse NEON development tool which is not able to execute the program after clicking on run button, and I don't get to see any error messages it throws after compilation. It shows the Windows 10 dialog for non executed program, where it says "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Program which i am trying to run-

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int first;
 int second;
 int *firstreference;
 int *secondreference;

 void calledbyvalue(int input);
 void calledbyreference(int *input);

  void calledbyvalue(int input){

   //disabling the buffer
   setbuf(stdout, NULL);

   printf("Enter the first value - ");
   scanf("%d", &input);
   printf("Value entered for first is - %d", input);
   printf("Entered input is - %d",input);

  }

  void calledbyreference(int *inputreference){

    //disabling the buffer
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);

    printf("Enter the second value - ");
    scanf("%d", &inputreference);
    printf("Value entered for second is - %d", inputreference);
    printf("Entered input reference value is - %d",&inputreference);

   }

   void main(){

   *firstreference = &first;
   *secondreference = &second;

  //Calling user defined functions here .... 
  calledbyvalue(first);
  calledbyreference(firstreference);

 calledbyvalue(second);
 calledbyreference(secondreference);

}
```

Comment: That means your program has crashed. You should run in a debugger to catch the crash in action to find out where in your code it happens. In the debugger you will also be able to examine variables an their values to help you figure out what might have caused the crash.

Comment: Your code should be causing the compiler to emit a lot of warnings, and if not then you need to change the build-settings so it does. Compiler warnings are often equally serious as compiler errors, as they can indicate you doing something wrong that will cause *undefined behavior* and possibly crashes when running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part

```
*firstreference = &first;
*secondreference = &second;
```

invokes *undefined behavior* by dereferencing `NULL`, which is the initial value of static pointer variables with no explicit initialization. Do not do that. To assign pointers to `first` and `second`, use

```
firstreference = &first;
secondreference = &second;
```

Also the part

```
scanf("%d", &inputreference);
printf("Value entered for second is - %d", inputreference);
printf("Entered input reference value is - %d",&inputreference);
```

invokes *undefined behavior* by passing pointer to object having wrong type to `scanf()` and passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. What you want may be this:

```
scanf("%d", inputreference);
printf("Value entered for second is - %d", *inputreference);
printf("Entered input reference value is - %d",*inputreference);
```

One more note is that you should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.